# i return a json object and i get an output

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

i return a json object and i get wrong output. 
I want for the json object to print CompanyName, AdressCompany and PhoneCompany.
what do i need to change in the getProductData? 
This is our code:

```
public ActionResult GetProductData(int ProductId)
        {
            var data = from m in db.Products
                  join sa in db.SupPro on m.ProductID equals sa.ProductID
                  join f in db.Supplier on sa.CompanyID equals f.CompanyID
                  where m.ProductID == ProductId
                  select new { CompanyName = f.NameS, AdressCompany = f.Address, PhoneCompany = f.Phone };
            return Json(new { foo = data.ToList(), ball = "dragon", elementId = ProductId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

this is my output: 
data res :[object Object]

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to get the result of the query, just the generated query or both?

Comment: What is the point of trying to return a `string`? And what is the value you are expecting?

Comment: i return a json object and a json object expects a string in the parameters he gets.

Comment: Nope... it will _automatically_ convert your object into a string, which it will then pass to the response.

Comment: The value of `foo` will be an object containing each property/value of the results of your query which is what it should be (you would not be able to access the values if it wasn't)

Comment: I get and error in the output: "already data reader open associated with this command" when im not returning a string for json

Comment: That's a problem related to the sql reader, which might be already opened from another query request.

Comment: Then you need to materialize your query (using `.ToList()`, not `ToString()`)

Comment: I tried it and the error is : "Circular reference detected while serializing an object of type"  System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SupPro_8C6D0751525397725CE757C5B55C4E144C5E94D‌​AF9869481208CFF841D0F68CA

Comment: `SupPro` contains `Customer` and `Customer` contains `ICollection<SupPro>` causing the circular reference. Use a `Select(x => new { ...});` to create a collection of anonymous objects containing only those properties you need on the client (I don't know what they are)

Comment: Can you give an example with more details? thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what data you need on the client but it might be `var data = res.Select(x => new { SupProID = x.SupProID, NameS = x.Customer.NameS, etc...})`

Comment: ok i tried it and it prints me an: [object Object]

Comment: @GalSosin, You have not shown your client code so how do you expect help. If you wanted to access the `SupProID` value then it would need to be something like `var id = response.res.SupProID;`

Comment: What code do you need me to add?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to achieve here is the following:

```
var res = (from e in db.SupPro
           join sa in db.Supplier on e.CompanyID equals sa.CompanyID
           where e.ProductID == ProductId
           select sa).ToList();

return Json(new { foo = res, ball = "dragon", elementId = ProductId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This will trigger reading the data from the database and set it as the value of the `foo` property in your JSON response.

Comment: It dosent work the error is : "Circular reference detected while serializing an object of type"  System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SupPro_8C6D0751525397725CE757C5B55C4E144C5E94DAF9869481208CFF841D0F68CA

Comment: Then you have a circular reference in your query (you have a property which is a collection of the class). Modify it to return a collection of anonymous objects containing only those properties you need to return. You need to show your model

Comment: this is the Model:  public class SupPro
    {
        [Key]
        public int SupProID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public DateTime SupplyDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Products Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Edit your question (not in comments). And you need to show all the models - `Product`, `Supplier` and `Customer` - one of those objects contains a property which is one of the other classes - e.g. Product contains Supplier and Supplier contains collection of Products

Comment: i added it in my main question.